# Using both @ErrorTemplate annotation and custom ConstraintViolationException mapper results in race condition

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation, jersey-2.0

I'm working on a Jersey project that uses a custom [ConstraintViolationException](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) mapper which builds and returns a JSON response. This JSON response is not what I want in all cases, there are some resources that I would like to respond with HTML.

[@ErrorTemplate](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html#d0e13509) seemed to be a perfect solution to suit my needs. However, after registering `MvcBeanValidationFeature.class` as required and annotating the methods I wanted to respond with HTML I have a race condition somewhere.

The newly annotated with `@ErrorTemplate` methods work fine and return HTML using the provided template.

The resource methods that I haven't touched and would normally respond with JSON **do not always** do that anymore. When I place a breakpoint in the custom `ConstraintViolationException` mapper then I get JSON, otherwise the custom mapper is never called and I get the default response, e.g.

```
{
   "code" : 400,
   "message" : "Description field can't be empty.",
   "date" : "2014-11-13T15:28:23.556Z"
}
```

vs the default:

```
<div class="validation-errors">
<div class="validation-error">
<span class="message">Description field can't be empty.</span>(
    <span class="path">
    <strong>path</strong>=
    FormResources.createTicket.arg0.description</span>,
    <span class="invalid-value">
    <strong>invalidValue</strong>= null</span>
)</div>
</div>
```

I'm fairly new to Jersey and can't quite figure out what the problem is. `@ErrorTemplate` annotation is handled by a custom `ExceptionMapper` so I suppose the problem/clash is somewhere there.

Have I misconfigured something? Is it at all possible to have dual error handling like this?

My thinking was that the decision of which exception handler was going to be used was based on the presence of either `@Valid` or `@ErrorTemplate` annotations...

Here is my configuration snippet:

```
    register(JsonConfiguration.class);
    register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    register(MvcBeanValidationFeature.class);
    register(ValidationFeature.class);
    property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    property(FreemarkerMvcFeature.TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH, "/templates");
    register(FreemarkerMvcFeature.class);
```

the custom mapper:

```
@Override
public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
    Response build = Response
            .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .entity(new ErrorResponse(
                    Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(),
                    exception.getConstraintViolations().iterator().next().getMessage()
            ))
            .build();
    return build;
}
```

an example resource method that is supposed to return JSON on errors but doesn't always do that any more:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public TicketEntity createTicket(@Valid TicketEntity te) throws Exception {
```

an example resource method that returns HTML on errors:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
@ErrorTemplate(name = TEMPLATE_FORM_VALIDATION_ERROR)
public Viewable createTicketFromForm(
    @NotNull(message = "The ticket must contain a description.")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "The ticket must contain a description.")
    @FormParam("description") String paramDescription,
    ...
```

and finally the extra addition to the POM, namely `jersey-mvc-bean-validation`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-bean-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```